# Hidden value wont fire in my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden field value which changes. In my javascript, I was hoping to detect this change and pass values to my php script.

I have read that hidden field values change event need to be triggered. Since this value is always changing how do I go about it.

Below is the code I tried:

```
 $('#supp').val().trigger('change');

 $('#supp').change(function ()
{
    populate();
})
```

This gives me a console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method trigger.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#supp').trigger('change');
```

Don't use `val()` before hand, because it returns a string, number or array.

However, if you're SETTING a value, which I assume you are, `val()` returns `jQuery`.

```
$('#supp').val('newValue').trigger('change');
```

Also, you'll need to bind your `change()` handler before attempting to trigger it.

Comment: Error gone, I note I need to  call the function populate when a value exists in my hidden field. The change is not triggered with this code  likely because of a postback.

Comment: Then check for a value: `if($('#supp').val() != "") populate();`